# Print out certain line of file

Tags: text-processing, sed

I'm trying to print out all the words in misspelled (which is 
"rools
hatte"
).

But I keep being given the error

> sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unterminated `s' command

I've tried different ways I've found on this website and elsewhere, but I always get this error regardless.

```
linecount="$(wc -l < misspelled)"
echo -e "MISSPELLED: \t\t\t CORRECT:"
for NUM in 'seq $linecount'
do
    sed "${NUM}q;d" misspelled
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong type of quotes around `seq $linecount`.  You have single quotes, which make the whole phrase get treated as a single string.  If you want to execute it and use the results you want backticks:

```
`seq $linecount`
```

or, better now, use the `$(...)` syntax which does the same

```
for num in $(seq $linecount)
```

or you could do it without the other program at all:

```
num=1
while [ "$num" -le "$linecount" ]; do
    ...
    ((num=num+1))
done
```

If you're trying to print out the first `N` lines of the file though you should probably use just `head`:

```
head -n "$linecount" misspelled
```

Comment: Hey thanks for all the help. I had one more question. I wanted the output formatted like in a way that woul dhave the misspellings under the MISSPELLING text. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: I finally got it, thank you so much for the help! Youre the best!